# Is there any way to get the hidden filed populated at client side on server through Get Action MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

I have a requirement where i have a hidden field which i am populating through jquery and want to access that on next document ready or load. Same hidden filed values are accessible if page load through POST action but same hidden filed is null if page is getting loaded though GET action. Please let me know if this can be achieved.

Populating hidden field on selection

```
function PreserveCheckBoxSelection() {
            $('#SelectedCheckboxIds').val('');
            var teamIds = "";

$('#WebGridResult').find("input[name='checkBoxIds']").each(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    teamIds += (this.defaultValue + ',');
                }
            });
            if (teamIds != "") {
                teamIds = teamIds.substring(0, teamIds.length - 1);
                $('#SelectedCheckboxIds').val(teamIds);
            }
}
```

On document ready, accessing it & marking checkbox as selected

```
(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#SelectedCheckboxIds').val() != 'undefined' && $('#SelectedCheckboxIds').val() != '' ) {
                var teamIds= $('#SelectedCheckboxIds').val();
                var arrayTeamIds = teamIds.split(",");
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayTeamIds.length; i++) {
                    $('#WebGridResult').find("input[name='checkBoxIds']").each(function () {
                        if (this.defaultValue == arrayTeamIds[i]) {
                            this.checked =true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
});
```

this hidden field in model

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedCheckboxIds)
```

Comment: Are your hidden fields in between the <form> and </form> tags?

Comment: No its in body tag